Drupal Media Files Automatically getting removed
Currently we are facing an issue i.e Our media files are getting deleted from hosting folder automatically after random interval.
For instance Media information and its meta remains there but its related files are getting removed every time we upload and after few days or right after one day , Files get deleted from server
What we have already checked

No Crons are running on Drupal instance
Extensions which are being used are same as of our staging instance but we are not facing this issue on our staging server.

Drupal version we are using 10.2.5
Application is hosted in Azure.
Can someone assist in what could be the issue e.g file inconsistencies with drupal or and cleanup bug may it have ?
Screenshot of issue
We tried

No Crons are configured
Tried with different names of images (in progress) to reproduce the issue.

Expect

Images / Media file should not deleted automatically and should be there permanently unless someone deletes from Drupal management system


I have had some media files on my Drupal instance for over 5 years now.
I am not using Azure.  I am self-hosted.
My guess is that this is the outcome of an automated Azure process that you may not know about; one that has been designed to "help" tenants stay within their disk quota.  Hopefully, the following URL will lead you to a solution.  It is a description of a "reaper" process that automagically deletes files in Azure storage on behalf of tenants.  You may, unknowingly, have one of those processes running.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/delete-activity
